# How do I access my instance 'this' from revealing prototype?

Tags: javascript, this, revealing-prototype

I want to use the Revealing Prototype pattern, let's say I have a simple object

```
function Obj(name) {
    this.name = name;
}

Obj.prototype = (function() {
    var p1 = function() {
        return p2();
    };

    var p2 = function() {
        return this.name;
    };

    return {
        f1: p1,
        f2: p2
    };
}());
```

I construct with

```
var o = new Obj('Hello');
```

now `o.f2()` gives me `Hello` but `o.f1()` gives me `undefined`. I am able to get around this by passing the scope via call such as `p2.call(this)`, however this becomes combersome with a lot of functions. Ideally I would want to be able to do a `self = this` type assignment so that I can just do `self.name` anywhere in the code.

How do I do this?

Comment: You really can't do that. The prototype functions have to deal with the fact that `this` may be different for each invocation. (Of course some genius may know something clever; I haven't had much coffee this morning :)

Comment: Is there a best practice then to manage code like this? Using call all the time get's messy and confusing!

Comment: I'll add an answer with one possible approach.

Comment: Just wondering: I thought overwriting an Object's prototype was not a safe thing to do & that it would be better to add all this in methods like: `Obj.prototype.someMethod = `.. Is this true?

Comment: @Tyblitz Overriding the prototype can have negative effects, but in this case the prototype is changed before any instances have been created, so it's OK. Things get weird when the prototype changes *after* instances have been created, because old instances retain the old prototype.

Comment: Just don't call `p2()`, but `this.f2()`?

Answer (score 1):

Because the nature of JavaScript function invocation is what it is, and because the prototype code has to work for any of its "client" objects, it's hard to eliminate the explicit management of the context (`this`).  One possible approach that may be preferable to using `.call()` or `.apply()` all over the place is to transform the functions such that the context is made an explicit parameter. You can do this with `.call()` and `.bind()`:

```
Obj.prototype = (function() {
    var p1 = function() {
        return cp2(this);
    };

    var p2 = function() {
        return this.name;
    };

    var cp1 = p1.call.bind(p1);
    var cp2 = p2.call.bind(p2);

    return {
        f1: p1,
        f2: p2
    };
}());
```

With that, "cp1" and "cp2" are basically aliases that can be used instead of the explicit reference to `.call()`.  The first argument is the value to be used as the context.

Note that in the prototype, you *don't* want to bind anything to `this`, since it's different for each object instance.